# Creating Average Grid data from Co-ordinate and value data

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider a list:

```
ZXV = {{z1, x1, v1}, {z2, x2, v2},........................}
```

where $z$ is Z co-ordinate, $x$ is X co-ordinate, $v$ is the value at the point $i$.

I want to create a grid based on squares 100 units wide.  I then want to calculate the average value within the grid.

I then want to create a list of averages, with the centre point of each square - `{{cz1, cx1, av1}, {cz2, cx2, av2}, .......}`  where $cz$ is centre for $z$, $cx$ is centre for $x$, and $av$ is average value for the square unit.

I was looking at something like

```
Split[mylist, Chop[#2 - #1 - 1] == 0 &]
```

but I need to setup recursive loop [2#-#1], [#3- #1], [#4 - #1]  until the rule [#Number - #1] > 100 is reached

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

```
mylist = Transpose[{RandomReal[100, 1000], RandomReal[100, 1000], RandomReal[1, 1000]}];

binned = GatherBy[#, Floor[#[[2]]] &] & /@ GatherBy[mylist, Floor[#[[1]]] &];

means = Join @@ Map[Mean, binned, {2}];

BubbleChart[Tooltip /@ means, GridLines -> {Range@100, Range@100}, 
            BubbleSizes -> {0.005, .005}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thks - very useful. Here is a sample of the data. Pls can you apply. list = {{5.16262, 11.872, -1.2275}, {5.16262, 12.64, -1.1461}, {5.16262, 12.672, -1.1435}, {5.16262, 12.8, -1.1372}, {5.16262, 12.832, -1.1356}, {5.16262, 12.864, -1.1388}, {5.16262, 12.896, -1.1416}, {5.16262, 12.928, -1.139}, {5.16262, 12.96, -1.1374}, {5.16262, 12.992, -1.1372}, {5.16262, 13.024, -1.1341}, {5.16262, 13.056, -1.129}, {5.16262, 13.088, -1.1346}, {5.16262, 13.12, -1.1337}, {5.16262, 13.152, -1.1323}, {5.16262, 13.184, -1.133}, {5.16262, 13.216, -1.1358}, {5.16262, 13.248, -1.1383}}

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `Partition` to form the group of four points, and then calculate the mean value in each group.

For example here are some data on a 100 by 100 grids

```
data = N@Table[Cos[x^2 + y^2], {x, π/100, π, π/100}, {y, π/100, π, π/100}];
```

To form a group of four point

```
data1 = Partition[data, {2, 2}, 1];
```

then the mean value is

```
data2= Map[Mean[Mean[#]] &, data1, {2}];
```

If your data has the form of {{x1,y1,z1},..} shape, then you can apply this to each dimension

```
dataXYZ = 
 N@Table[{x, y, Cos[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, π/100, π, π/100}, {y, π/100, π, π/100}];

Transpose[Map[Mean[Mean[#]] &, Partition[#, {2, 2}, 1], {2}] & /@ 
  Transpose[dataXYZ, {2, 3, 1}], {3, 1, 2}]
```

Here is an example shows what it does, where the black dots are the original grid and the red dots are the center of each square.

```
grid1 = Table[{i, j}, {i, 10}, {j, 10}];
grid2 = Transpose[Map[Mean[Mean[#]] &, Partition[#, {2, 2}, 1], {2}] & /@ 
   Transpose[grid1, {2, 3, 1}], {3, 1, 2}]
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[Flatten[grid1, 1]], Red, 
  Point[Flatten[grid2, 1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thks - very useful. Here is a sample of the data. Pls can you apply.  list = {{5.16262, 11.872, -1.2275}, {5.16262, 12.64, -1.1461}, {5.16262, 
  12.672, -1.1435}, {5.16262, 12.8, -1.1372}, {5.16262, 
  12.832, -1.1356}, {5.16262, 12.864, -1.1388}, {5.16262, 
  12.896, -1.1416}, {5.16262, 12.928, -1.139}, {5.16262, 
  12.96, -1.1374}, {5.16262, 12.992, -1.1372}, {5.16262, 
  13.024, -1.1341}, {5.16262, 13.056, -1.129}, {5.16262, 
  13.088, -1.1346}, {5.16262, 13.12, -1.1337}, {5.16262, 
  13.152, -1.1323}, {5.16262, 13.184, -1.133}, {5.16262, 
  13.216, -1.1358}, {5.16262, 13.248, -1.1383}}

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have this data, just using a random set here for completeness,

```
SeedRandom[55];
(* A set of random 2D coordinates *)
list = RandomReal[100, {1000, 2}];
(* attach a set of less-random values as the third coordinate *)

list = {#1, #2, #1 + #2 + RandomReal[{-50, 50}]} & @@@ list;
```

You can view the data using a `ListDensityPlot` or `ListPlot`,

```
ListDensityPlot[list, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
ListPlot[Style[{#1, #2}, ColorData["Rainbow"][#3/100]] & @@@ list, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 100, 20], Range[0, 100, 20]}]
```

[image]

You can see that the values generally get larger as `x` and `z` get larger, but that density plot is horrible.

To get a list of the values in a particular rectangular region, use `Select`:

```
Last/@Select[list, 0 <= #[[1]] <= 20 && 0 <= #[[2]] <= 20 &]

(*  {37.5551, 1.32275, 16.2364, 66.5277, 18.6801,......, 15.8541, 25.897, 33.8019, 19.1619} *)
```

And you can just use `Mean` to get the mean value in that region (or `Total` to get the total value).

Use `Table` to collect all the mean values over, for example, a 5 by 5 grid,

```
{dx, dz} = {20, 20};
gridmean = Table[
   Mean[
    Last /@ 
     Select[list, x <= #[[1]] <= x + dx && z <= #[[2]] <= z + dz &]
    ]
   , {x, 0, 80, dx}, {z, 0, 80, dz}];
```

And then use `ListDenistyPlot` to show the mean values,

```
ListDensityPlot[gridmean, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, DataRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could create a list of `Rectangle` objects and use `RegionMember` to select the points,

```
regions = 
  Table[Rectangle[{x, z}, {x + dx, z + dz}], {x, 0, 80, dx}, {z, 0, 
    80, dz}];
gridmean = Table[
  Mean[
   Last /@ Select[list, RegionMember[regions[[n, m]], #[[;; 2]]] &]
   ], {n, 5}, {m, 5}]
```

But this is a bit slower